# What is the format of this data? Mapbox Javascript issues

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson

Ive been trying to create a Mapbox plot like this one: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/) using javascript.

Im trying to create this using data from psql (with feature columns including lat and long) passed through a Python (flask) backend into my html file. I can get the linked plot to work, but can't see how to get my own data in there. Ive tried map.addSource with a GeoJSON file of features but I just can't get it to work. I feel like if I could replicate the data in the link they use I could plot it but I can't see the data!

Any ideas would be great! Im new to JS so the although ive read the documentation I might be missing bits.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Style circles with a data-driven property</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
  <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
  <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
    // ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
    // https://account.mapbox.com
    mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
      zoom: 12,
      center: [-122.447303, 37.753574]
    });

    map.on('load', function() {
      /* Sample feature from the `examples.8fgz4egr` tileset:
      {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
      "ethnicity": "White"
      },
      "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [ -122.447303, 37.753574 ]
      }
      }
      */
      map.addSource('ethnicity', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://examples.8fgz4egr'
      });
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'population',
        'type': 'circle',
        'source': 'ethnicity',
        'source-layer': 'sf2010',
        'paint': {
          // make circles larger as the user zooms from z12 to z22
          'circle-radius': {
            'base': 1.75,
            'stops': [
              [12, 2],
              [22, 180]
            ]
          },
          // color circles by ethnicity, using a match expression
          // https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-match
          'circle-color': [
            'match', ['get', 'ethnicity'],
            'White',
            '#fbb03b',
            'Black',
            '#223b53',
            'Hispanic',
            '#e55e5e',
            'Asian',
            '#3bb2d0',
            /* other */
            '#ccc'
          ]
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox GL JS supports GeoJSON source or Vector source to show vector data. i.e there's no other choice to show the data. Here's some options.

1. Vector tileset
   Generating Vector tileset is a bit heavy operation but it is a good choice for client performance

1-1. Host on Mapbox: Managing vector tileset hosted on Mapbox server by using MTS.
1-2. Host on your server: Creating vector tileset on your server by using tippecanoe tool and hosting on your server.

2. GeoJSON
   In general, you will create an endpoint that returns full GeoJSON generated from the database. If the size of GeoJSON is large, it is a nice idea to implement endpoint that takes coordinate and returns nearby data.

In this case, I ended up using geojson in Python to create the json file from the SQLAlchemy data and then passed that from the back end and passed it through to the html file using jinja2.

Then I did:

```
var data = JSON.parse(‘{{ json_data | tojson }}’)
```

And then sourced this data into my map!!!

Took a bit of playing around but this seems the smoothest way to get the SQLAlchemy data onto mapbox. Things might get slower when working with more than 200 rows of data But it’s a good solution for now!